# Untraceable root error android eclipse - no errors showing on files

Tags: android, eclipse, trace

An android project in eclipse has errors on root level but cannot be traced... It only show the error icon but no error in the code. I have other projects that run without errors in this same version of Eclipse.  Just have no idea how to trace the error for this one project.  No errors show on any of the src, xml, layout (etc) files.  How do I fix this?  Running Eclipse Juno and Android SDK 20.

Comment: I've upgraded the Java build path to 1.6 - No luck.  I've cleaned the project, no luck.  There are just no clues to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: i there any info on java console ? sometimes it provides some additional help, like expired certificate incorrect resource name etc

Comment: No info on java console at all.  It doesn't even get that far, eclipse just says there are errors and they need to be fixed when I try and run it.

Comment: Screenshot: [link]http://web-nation.com/android/Screenshot2Error.jpg

Comment: delete the project and import it again. it might work. Or check the errors logs, or problems log..

Answer (score 2):

Select *Window -> Show View -> Problems* to see the error message (and please add it to the question).

Errors showing an exclamation mark icon are *Build path errors*. They are not related to your code, but instead to the setup of your project. Open the context menu of that project, select *Build Path -> Configure Build Path...* to open a dialog showing you all the related setting (source and output directories, referenced projects, referenced libraries and so). One of those options inside the dialog should also show an error icon.

And a side mark: If you use publicly available projects like [EmPubLite](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/27b8bd939313bf702664faadb43953c610c145ca/EmPubLite), please indicate that in the question, as such information may help.

Comment: I had the same issue and it was reflected in problems view. One of reference library was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the
 `Project >> Properties >> Java Compiler >> Enable project Specific Settings >> compiler compliance level >> Change to 1.5 or 1.6 or 1.7` 
If you still Get that Error, there might be an issue if you are using external Libs, `Right Click on the Project >> Properties >> Java Build Path >> Libraries >> Add Jars`(if your jar file is within the workspace `>> use external jars` if jar file is in Local Disk.

 Please post Logcat error to solve your issues easily.

Comment: You're right!  Was missing the correct path to one of my referenced libraries.  Problem fixed.  Right clicked on the project, went to Properties -> Java Build Path and clicked the library tab.  This showed me an error that the path to one of my libraries was invalid.

Comment: 07-31 23:43:59.859: D/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
07-31 23:43:59.859: D/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: please help its very important  it is not showing any error but just it just showing red maark..can any body help me pleaseeeeee